# Generating threads in for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, collision-detection

I am trying to separate my collision detection into separate `theads` to improve the efficiency. The code I have now is:

```
/*CHECK COLLISION HERE*/

    std::thread threads[6];

    Vector2 birdPointsArr[6];
    Vector2* birdPoints = getBirdPoints(birdPointsArr);
    //check each pipe
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        //only check pipes with viable x coords
        if (pipes[i]->getX() < birdPoints[2].x + 20 && pipes[i]->getX() + pipes[i]->getW() > birdPoints[4].x - 20)
        {
            //check both upper and lower pipe   
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Vector2 pipePointsArr[4];
                Vector2* pipePoints = getPipePoints(pipePointsArr, i, j);

                //only check pipes with viable y coords
                if (j == 0 && birdPoints[0].y > pipePoints[2].y + 20)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j == 1 && birdPoints[3].y < pipePoints[0].y - 20)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                threads[i] = std::thread([&]() {
                    //if x and y coords are viable, check collision
                    if (collisionDetection(birdPoints, pipePoints)) {
                        dead = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if(threads[i].joinable())
            threads[i].join();
    }
```

My concern is that I am creating and destroying several threads each frame. I am concerned that all this creation and destruction makes my code slower than if I were to leave it synchronous; however, I don't know how to really measure that. Would it be faster if I just reverted it to serial form?

Comment: Multithread programming is a complex topic.  It is far more than knowing how to start threads (that's why MT programmers get paid a lot more than single-thread-only programmers).  You have to learn proper synchronization, which synchronization objects to use and why, condition variables, etc.  Given all that, your issue requires a [mcve], and a good look-over from an MT experienced person.

Comment: 0x0000065C is probably a null pointer plus an offset. Gather some data with the help of a debugger and it'll probably help you narrow down the scope of the problem enough to make a good [mre]. The true beauty of making a good MRE is it often leads you to the solution without any help.

Comment: Oop. Question changed.the ultimate answer to, "Did this speed up my program?" is profile it and find out. But yes, spinning up and destroying threads could be more expensive than they are beneficial. But maybe not. The runtime could be dolling threads out to you from a pool. You might want to make a pool. And maybe the algorithm is just too interdependent to parallelize. Whole lot of maybe.

Comment: What about using OpenMP for this case? The resulting code should be simpler, easier to read and it should also solve your problem (oversubscription and possibly thread creation).